# "What was really amazing, is that, the house had a little balcony."

Tags: punctuation, commas, syntactic-analysis, past-tense, present-tense

Is this sentence correct?

> What was really amazing, is that, the house had a little balcony.

Comment: The sentence could be improved by writing instead, "What is really amazing is that the house has a little balcony," or "What was really amazing was that the house had a little balcony." The commas are not needed, and "is that" changes tense for apparently no reason.

Comment: Thanks, but is this a correct sentence structure? I mean, does it sound good in spoken and written English?

Comment: It's suffering from comatosis.

Comment: The two examples in my first comment sound OK when spoken or written, although there is nothing "really amazing" about a house having "a little balcony," is there?

Comment: Yes :) it was just an example of the structure. Thank you very much.

Comment: I answered this question on the assumption that you were interested not just in whether the punctuation was acceptable, but in whether the shift in verb tense posed any problems. In general, question askers at this site are expected to identify **in their questions** the nature of the issue they are trying to resolve, and the information they have uncovered on their own while trying to answer the question themselves. That way, we avoid answers that don't address the poster's question, or wander too far afield, or duplicate the questioner's prior research.

Comment: Note that the poster specifically says that the sentence is "just an example of the structure" that he or she is interested in. To me, that means that this question is either about bracketing "is that" with commas in a "What was X is/was that..." sentence structure, or about shifting from "What was" to "is that" in the same type of sentence structure, or both. Though it might be reasonable to close this question for not showing research, I think it isn't appropriate to close it as a request for proofreading. My answer discusses the sentence-structure issues generically, anyway. I would reopen.

Answer (score 3):

In spoken English, people say things like

> What was really amazing is that the house had a little balcony.

and no one has any trouble understanding the idea that those speakers are trying to convey. In written English, the landscape is somewhat different: Since writers have the opportunity to edit their thoughts before sending them out into the world, their readers may have somewhat more stringent expectations in the way of consistency and precision than they might have as listeners.

To a reader, the most unusual feature of the example sentence is the shift from "was amazing" to "is that" to "had a balcony." The main points of the sentence are that (1) the house had a balcony, and (2) this fact was amazing. The words "is that" are necessary to the sense of the sentence, but only because the writer chose to introduce the information with the introductory phrase "What was amazing..." The writer could have skipped the "is that"/"was that" element in the wording by expressing the two main ideas in a more succinct way, such as by saying

> The house had a little balcony, and this fact was amazing.

or

> Amazingly, the house had a little balcony.

But accepting that the writer did choose the form "What was amazing..." to open the sentence, a reader might wonder why the writer followed up with "is that" instead of "was that," given that the sentence at that point was functioning quite comfortably in past tense. This may or may not be an answerable question, and it may be a remarkably silly question for a reader to ask, but I think that more readers are likely to ask it than are likely to ask why the writer chose the words "was that" in the alternative version of the sentence

> What was really amazing was that the house had a little balcony.

Few writers want their readers to wonder about distracting trivialities like "Why did the writer use 'is that' instead of 'was that' in this sentence?" when they could instead be thinking "Hmm, the fact that the house had a little balcony was amazing; I wonder why."

As for punctuation—as Hot Licks's comment about com[m]atosis (above) suggests—there is no advantage to setting "is that" off with commas. If you read the sentence aloud, you won't notice any natural extra pause at either end of those two words; that's because "is that" is functioning not as a parenthetical phrase, but as a necessary counterpart to the words "What was" at the beginning of the sentence. Think of internal sentence punctuation—commas, semicolons, colons, em dashes, and parentheses—as interpretive road signs for sentences that are so complicated or long-winded that readers may need help finding their way through them correctly. If the way is smooth, straight, and clear, the reader (and you) can do without them.

Comment: Very well said. Thank you, Sven, for a kind and thorough answer to the question. +1

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to add emphasis or bring attention to how amazing it is, you could write it like so:

> What was really amazing, is that the house had a little balcony.

However, encasing `is that` between two commas is likely not what you intend to do.